# oracle 11g - sql plus not opening after installing oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I installed oracle 11g and im was trying to open sqlplus from command prompt but it is opening and closing in a fraction of second..I tried opening the sqlplus from the installed location as well. It still shows the same behaviour. Can anyone help me with a solution. I already uninstalled and installed the oracle twice for some other errors. Earlier it was working fine, but when I installed it the second time, sql plus is not opening and I have already set the path as ORACLE_HOME in the system variable.

It would be more helpful if someone solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

most probably there is some rpm package missing in Linux, make sure that oracle-rdbms-server-11gr2-preinstall rpm package is installed and if it still keeps failing use strace sqlplus and upload output here.